# The norm of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be hermitian matrix over the ring of quaternions with size $n\times n$ (So  the eigenvalues are positive real numbers). Let 
$x^{*}Ax\leq |x|^{2}$ for every nonzero column vector $x$ where $|x|=\sup_{A}||Ax||$.

Then we want to prove $||A||< \infty$.  In fact, we want to prove $A$ is bounded. How?

Comment: Excuse me, can you explain what is the "$|x|=\sup_{A}||Ax||$" means?
(The sup take over all hermitian matrix $A$??)

Comment: Yes. It is a norm.

Comment: You meant $<\infty$ right?

Comment: Yes, I edit this.